# Использование компонентов фреймворка

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, sass

Привет всем. Подскажите как сделать красиво и удобно.
Имеется сверстанный фреймворк примерно из 400 компонентов, сделанный на основе bootstrap4-0-02 альфа,
sass, font-awesome, jquery, gulp.
На данный момент чтобы использовать компоненты фреймфорка, приходится тянуть стили и javascript всех 400 компонентов из проекта в проект.
Это не красиво и не логично. Как сделать чтобы пользователь фреймфорка мог взять только те компоненты которые будет использовать.
Например у меня в фреймворке 50 вариантов меню, мне нужно только одно, как правильно его выдернуть и использовать. Этот же вопрос актуален и для джаваскрипта.

Уточняю все 50 меню лежат в одном файле, элементы относящиеся к попап окошкам в другом, все что относится к слайдерам в третьем и так далее.

Comment: Собирать разные варианты gulp-ом?

Comment: @hardsky Разные? Боюсь представить сколько комбинаций будет хотя бы при десяти вариантов выбора.

Answer (score 1):

DELETED.

Тогда нужно делить, иначе никак, ибо как сборщик будет искать стили, относящиеся только к нужному меню? По селекторам?

Генерация для каждого возможного сочетания `менюшек` и `попапушек` - долго, много (очень много, просто экспоненциально много) и неэффективно (раз одних меню 50 штук).

Comment: У меня нет разбиения по файлу для каждого компонента, все 50 меню в одном файле, все 30 попап окошек в другом файле. Так сделано потому что 90% стилей дает бустрап, и лишь небольшие правки касающиеся этого меню лежат/обьеденены в файл содержащий все меню

Comment: Тогда нужно делить, иначе никак, ибо как сборщик будет искать стили, относящиеся только к нужному меню? По селекторам? :)

Comment: я думаю про селекторы и парсер, но не уверен что это правильный путь

Comment: @ЕвгенийБондаренко Это, в принципе, может сработать, но это реализовать куда сложнее, нежели разделить по файлам, придётся строить карту что к чему в файлах и куда что брать.